# Run mutter window manager standalone

Tags: mutter, startx

I'm trying to run my window manager standalone on Debian 7 (i.e. without Gnome 3, which is currently installed). Apparently Gnome is already running the `mutter` window manager:

```
$ wmctrl -m
Name: Mutter
Class: N/A
PID: N/A
Window manager's "showing the desktop" mode: N/A
```

I can't seem to find the mutter executable to run it, though. It's not on the `$PATH` and none of the results from `locate mutter` look like executables to me: (note that `/usr/share/mutter/` and `/usr/lib/mutter/` are both directories in the below output)

```
$ sudo locate mutter
/usr/lib/libmutter.so.0
/usr/lib/libmutter.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib/mutter
/usr/lib/mutter/Meta-3.0.typelib
/usr/share/mutter
/usr/share/GConf/gsettings/mutter-schemas.convert
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/mutter.desktop
/usr/share/doc/gir1.2-mutter-3.0
/usr/share/doc/libmutter0
/usr/share/doc/mutter-common
/usr/share/doc/gir1.2-mutter-3.0/AUTHORS
/usr/share/doc/gir1.2-mutter-3.0/NEWS.gz
/usr/share/doc/gir1.2-mutter-3.0/README.gz
/usr/share/doc/gir1.2-mutter-3.0/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/gir1.2-mutter-3.0/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/gir1.2-mutter-3.0/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libmutter0/AUTHORS
/usr/share/doc/libmutter0/NEWS.gz
/usr/share/doc/libmutter0/README.gz
/usr/share/doc/libmutter0/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libmutter0/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/libmutter0/copyright
/usr/share/doc/mutter-common/AUTHORS
/usr/share/doc/mutter-common/NEWS.gz
/usr/share/doc/mutter-common/README.gz
/usr/share/doc/mutter-common/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/mutter-common/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/mutter-common/copyright
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.mutter.gschema.xml
/usr/share/gnome-control-center/keybindings/50-mutter-windows.xml
/usr/share/locale/am/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/ar/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/as/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/ast/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/az/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/be/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/be@latin/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/bn/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/bn_IN/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/br/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/bs/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/ca/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/ca@valencia/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/cy/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/da/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/dz/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/el/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/en_CA/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/eo/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/et/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/eu/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/fa/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/fi/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/ga/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/gl/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/gu/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/ha/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/he/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/hi/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/hr/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/hu/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/hy/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/id/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/ig/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/is/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/ka/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/kn/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/ko/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/ku/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/la/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/lt/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/lv/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/mai/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/mg/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/mk/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/ml/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/mn/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/mr/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/ms/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/nb/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/nds/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/pa/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/pt/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/ro/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/rw/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/si/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/sk/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/sl/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/sq/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/sr/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/sr@latin/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/ta/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/te/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/th/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/tk/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/ug/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/uk/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/vi/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/wa/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/xh/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/yo/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/zh_HK/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/mutter.mo
/usr/share/man/man1/mutter-message.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mutter-theme-viewer.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mutter-window-demo.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mutter.1.gz
/usr/share/mutter/icons
/usr/share/mutter/icons/mutter-window-demo.png
/var/lib/dpkg/info/gir1.2-mutter-3.0.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/gir1.2-mutter-3.0.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libmutter0.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libmutter0.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libmutter0.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libmutter0.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libmutter0.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mutter-common.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mutter-common.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mutter-common.preinst
```

To get the window manager running my thinking was that I would just turn off the Gnome Desktop Manager and then run X from `.xinitrc` like so:

```
$ /etc/init.d/gdm3 stop
$ cat .xinitrc
#!/bin/bash
[[ -f ~/.Xresources ]] && xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
exec mutter
exec xterm -maximized
$ startx
```

Is this the right way to go about starting an xterm with the window manager enabled? I think I remember reading somewhere that only one `exec` is allowed in `.xinitrc`, so maybe I am trying this the wrong way?

Comment: When I try to run `mutter` standalone, it refuses and complains about "unsupported session". So I'm running `kwin_wayland` instead. It doesn't complain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exec mutter` replaces the script by `mutter`, so nothing below that line runs. If you want to run `xterm` before `mutter`:

```
xterm -maximized &
exec mutter
```

If you want to run `mutter` before `xterm`:

```
mutter &
wm_pid=$!
xterm -maximized &
wait $wm_pid
```

Alternatively, configure mutter to run `xterm -maximized` when it starts. I don't know whether this is possible — mutter is designed not to be configurable.

As for finding the mutter executable, it's already on the search path (in `/usr/bin`) if you installed it through the package manager, you have nothing to do.

Comment: very good :) any tips on finding where the mutter executable is?

Comment: actually never mind. i just went `sudo apt-get install mutter` and now its on the `$PATH`. i will add this to your answer

Comment: i just checked and even `sudo locate ...` does not look inside `/usr/bin/` so mutter was probably there all along!

Comment: @mulllhausen `locate` definitely looks inside `/usr/bin`. It looks like your locate database isn't up-to-date. Run `sudo updatedb`.

Comment: i could have sworn i did that! haha well you are right - its looking in there now :P

Comment: i like the second method you posted as it should work with the `maximised` flag. however it seems to be a race condition and sometimes the xterm is not maximised (i'm guessing because the window manager has not finished initialising by the time the `xterm` command runs). any tips on checking if it is loaded before running the `xterm -maximized` command? maybe using `wmctrl`?

Comment: @mulllhausen [`xtoolwait xterm &`](https://github.com/dlitz/xtoolwait) (there's a Debian package). But if you're trying to do anything fancy, Mutter is probably not the window manager for you. There are dozens of window managers around, including some that are designed for configurability.

Comment: its ok i like that mutter is minimal. i'm actually really pleased with my setup now! many thanks for all the help. `xtoolwait` looks like just the thing i'm after. i got it working with `sleep 2` but that was pretty dodgy